# Ubuntu 18.04 after successful installation of Odoo 13, now I can't see ubuntu desktop

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, odoo, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed Odoo 13 on Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox VM, all done successfully, i got first screen in my browser where it asks to create database, I shutdown machine completely, start again but not have ubuntu desktop, increased ram from 4GB to 8GB still failed, display ram from 16MB to 32MB but failed, processor from 1 to 2 but still failed, can someone help me to have my vm working normally?
i followed this guide (till **Testing the Installation** only): https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-odoo-13-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Then i think this is not an odoo error right? Something went wrong with your VM. Update your question tags so someone will definitely help you.

Comment: I think you should use Ubuntu Server in your vm to consume fewer resources

Comment: also I used a Script file from github for installation of Odoo and tried on 3 different laptops but on all machines its same behaviour. not yet found any guide to install it on a Ubuntu Server, will try to install it on Ubuntu Server may be this can resolve the problem.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention, can't use Ubuntu Server as its an Odoo Developer VM which also required Pycharm and/or Visual Studio Code and Firefor/Chrome/Edge, so developers can have their own machines on laptops where ever they are.